# Can a false timestamp on a makefile break a build?

Tags: makefile, timestamp

Today, I tried to run a building script on sources that were in a mounted NAS directory. During the build, I received a warning saying that one of the cmake generated files had a modification time 13 s in the future. Subsequently the build failed, because a header file could not be found.

Now, this building script has never given me any troubles before, and the header file was exactly where it was supposed to be, so I was quite puzzled by the error. However, when I inspected the cmake generated file with the false timestamp, it turned out to contain the CCX_INCLUDES. This makes me suspect that the timestamp is in fact the cause of the problem, but I do not understand how it can influence the build. Could someone please shed a light on this?

Comment: Make uses timestamps to determine if a target is out of date (and whether to rebuild it).   If you have a corrupt timestamp, it could mean that make didn't rebuild something it should have, and that can cause a build failure.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but this was a clean build.